# Placing table element on top of a gif background

Tags: html, css

I have encountered a little problem no matter what I've tried I could not find the right solution for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<head>
<style>
table.table2, table.table1 {
    width: 190.5px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: red;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.table1, td, th, table.table2 td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
div{
  background-image: url(https://media.nature.com/lw800/magazine-assets/d41586-018-04158-5/d41586-018- 
  04158-5_15590100.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100%;

}
html , body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<table class="table1">
<thead><tr><th>Focus</th><th>State</th><th>Alert Level</th></tr></thead>
<tr><td>Eyes</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr> 
<tr><td>Head</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr>
<tr><td>Body</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr>
<tr><td>Vehicle</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr>
</table>
<table class="table2">
<thead><tr><th>Current action</th></tr></thead>
<tr><td> vaction </td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The thing is I want this table to be in the top left corner in front of the gif background, any ideas how could I do that? :)

Comment: Have you try to change the position of your table :  `position: absolute` in your CSS ?

Comment: Yeah I did try it. :/

Comment: Do you want to position your table in the middle of the background or just in top of it, I can help

Comment: I want the background to fully cover the page and the table to be in the top left corner on top of the background, i could show you a picture but I cannot upload it here

Comment: https://ibb.co/VNVpLhL This is what I would like it to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
table.table2, table.table1 {
  width: 190.5px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.table1, td, th, table.table2 td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
html , body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.cover {
  background-image: url(https://media.nature.com/lw800/magazine-assets/d41586-018-04158-5/d41586-018-04158-5_15590100.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover"> 
  <div>
    <table class="table1">
    <thead><tr><th>Focus</th><th>State</th><th>Alert Level</th></tr></thead>
    <tr><td>Eyes</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr> 
    <tr><td>Head</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Body</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Vehicle</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr>
    </table>

    <table class="table2">
    <thead><tr><th>Current action</th></tr></thead>
    <tr><td> vaction </td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: I'm Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did this.

```css
table.table2, table.table1 {
    width: 190.5px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.table1, td, th, table.table2 td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#myDiv{
  background-image: url("https://www.automotor-france.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/01-01-1.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 10rem;
  width:5rem;

}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
<table class="table1">
<thead><tr><th>Focus</th><th>State</th><th>Alert Level</th></tr></thead>
<tr><td>Eyes</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr> 
<tr><td>Head</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr>
<tr><td>Body</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr>
<tr><td>Vehicle</td><td> state </td><td> level </td></tr>
</table>
<table class="table2">
<thead><tr><th>Current action</th></tr></thead>
<tr><td> vaction </td></tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by Background? The image is in the background of Table now!?

Comment: So, is it what you meant?